# Расскажите мне как правильно подключать порядок link в head?

Tags: html, css

Расскажите мне как правильно подключать порядок link в head

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/media.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/reset.css">
 
</head>
```

Comment: ИМХО. Просто руководствуйтесь тем,что страница может некорректно отобразиться до полной загрузки внешнего CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала `reset.css`, потом `style.css`, а затем `media.css`.

По крайней мере `reset.css` точно должен быть в начале, потому что он сбрасывает стили браузера, а уже в `style.css` определяются необходимые стили